# Display submitted form data in Java Spring MVC bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, bootstrap-modal

What I am trying to do: Display a value entered into a form in the modal that is shown by submitting the form.

What I tried first: To simply reference the "id" element in the modal. Realized this probably would not work because the modal is generated during page load and before the form has any values. So the value will be empty.

What I am currently trying: To return the form value after submission from my controller. Use boostrap Table('load', data) to load the table after form return and display in the modal.

I am very new to Java and feel like I may be making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be. Here is the current code:

If any additional code snippets needed, let me know...

javascript - I know I am making it into submit.done because the table is displaying, just no data.

```
$table = $("#notesTable").bootstrapTable({
    data: []
});
$("#notesTable").hide(); 
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    var dataString = $("#extractForm").serialize();
    var submit = $.ajax({
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/doc/validateAuditId",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: dataString
    });
    submit.done(function(data) {
        if (data.length && data.length > 0) {
            $("#notesTable").show();
            $("#notesTable").bootstrapTable('load', data);
            $("#dlgUpload").modal('show');
            
        }else{
            $("#notesTable").hide();
            $("#dlgUpload").modal('show');
        }
    });
```

Return from controller

[image]

Modal:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="dlgUpload" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="noteTitle">Upload File</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="tabs-div">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tabUploadDoc" aria-controls="tabUploadDoc" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Upload Document</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tabDocType" aria-controls="tabDocType" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Select Doc Type</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tabPerceptiveContent" aria-controls="tabPerceptiveContent" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Perceptive Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tabUploadDoc">
                            <br>
                            <form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/doc/uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3 form-group">
                                    <form:label path="fileName">Select a file to upload:</form:label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-2 form-group">
                                    <input type="file" name="fileName" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    <table id="notesTable" data-classes="table table-striped table-no-bordered" data-undefined-text="" data-toggle="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-field="retAuditId" data-visible="true" data-align="left" data-sortable="false">Audit ID</th>
                        </tr>
                    </th>
```

Output:  Nada

[image]

Comment: I needed to return a <list> from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Need to return a list from the controller.  Was returning a String.